# Is there any solution to ltrace calls made by libs opened using dlopen()?

Tags: c, shared-library, trace, dynamic-loading, ltrace

I wrote different two different types of queues. Bundled them in different `.so`s. I have a driver `main.c` which tests functions offered by those queues. `main.c` makes use `dlfcn.h` to load, unload required library at run-time. Both the implementations of queue make use of standard library functions.

I wish to list number of `malloc`s and `free`s made by my library. So I did `ltrace -c ./exe.out` but, it could not catch any standard library calls made by my `dlopen()`ed libraries. All that `ltrace` could tap in was `dl*()` calls.

I checked SEE ALSO part of `man ltrace` and so read `man ltrace.conf` too. But the manual itself is bit obfuscated for beginners like me!

- How to trace calls made by `dlopen()`ed libraries using `ltrace` utility?
- Does configuring `/etc/ltrace.conf` help me deal this situation?

Comment: What version of `ltrace` are you using?

Comment: @StephenKitt, I am using ltrace 0.7.0
edit: am using 0.7.3 version